# Drawing Shapes Using Turtle

Tags: python, python-3.x, turtle-graphics

I'm trying to use Python/Turtle to achieve a result like this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lz4Eb.png

I drew the squares uneven in paint but I mean for them to be even. The squares can be any shape as well depending on the user input (for ex. 5 for polygons).

Here is my code so far:

```
import turtle
import time
import random

print ("This program draws shapes based on the number you enter in a uniform pattern.")
num_str = input("Enter the side number of the shape you want to draw: ")
if num_str.isdigit():
    squares = int(num_str)

angle = 180 - 180*(squares-2)/squares

turtle.color(random.random(),random.random(), random.random())
turtle.begin_fill()

count = 0
x = -80
y = -80
turtle.setpos(x,y)
turtle.down()

while count < 8:
    x += 50
    y += 50
    turtle.goto(x,y)
    for i in range(squares):
        count += 1
        turtle.forward(20)
        turtle.left(angle)
        turtle.forward(20)      
        print (turtle.pos())

turtle.end_fill()

time.sleep(15)
turtle.bye()
```

And here is what I get:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/u7gbP.png

The error I get is: How can I get it to print out 8 shapes total, instead of only 2, I though the loop would make it repeat 8 times because of the count += 1 < 8?

I thought the loop would change the position of x and y by adding 50, 50 each time and then I would tweak it to give the right coordinates to make the shape I want, but it won't even display all 8 yet?

I've spent a while reconfiguring the code but instead of doing trial and error forever, I figured maybe some help would work, thanks.

I am using Python 3.2.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you choose to display a shape with four sides, you're only going to draw two shapes. This is because you're increasing your loop counter *once per side* for *each shape*.

This is not a good way to do loops, counters are rarely necessary, and when they are - use `enumerate`

You want to try something like this.

```
numshapes = 8
for x in range(numshapes):
  x += 50
  y += 50
  turtle.goto(x,y)
  for i in range(squares):
      turtle.forward(20)
      turtle.left(angle)
      turtle.forward(20)      
      print (turtle.pos())
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and moved the turtle.up/down a bit and I got a pillar of 8 squares, now it's just a matter of positioning the squares in the way I want them in the picture above right?

Comment: Yeah I suppose so. Why are you calling `turtle.forward()` twice in that loop? It looks like you're drawing two sides for each side.

Comment: Positioning these squares the way I want them is pretty hard, does the turtle window act as a normal coordinate graph? I'm gonna have to make an algorithm/formula to position these squares because entering in diff x,y values is getting tedious...and I'm not experienced enough to explain why it's in there twice, but from what I can tell when I run the program, it doesn't seem to draw it twice..?